# Why is my RSS feed file_get_contents not working?

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, rss, file-get-contents

I'm trying to set up a live feed from a blog, but the contents are not displays. Any ideas? The blog is based in WP, I've set a contents curl below to a php file. The php file contains another curl to the physical blog feed.

```
<?php

try{

            // Get RSS feed
            $blog_feed = @file_get_contents_curl('http://www.coordsport.com/csblogfeed.php');

if ($blog_feed){

            // Convert to traversable XML object
            $blog_posts = new SimpleXMLElement($blog_feed);

            // Set limits and counter
            $list_count = 5;
            $current_item = 0;

            // Loop through each feed item
            foreach ($blog_posts->channel->item as $blog_post)
            {
                // Increment counter and check count
                if (++$current_item > $list_count) break;

                // Force data type for description
                $post_description = (string)$blog_post->description;

                $desc_xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<div>' . $post_description . '</div>');

                // Reset thumbnail
                $thumbnail_src = '';

                if (@$desc_xml->img[0])
                {
                    $thumbnail_src = (string) $desc_xml->img[0]->attributes()->src;
                }

}
else
{
echo 'Error Loading Feed';
}

    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
            echo 'Error Loading Feed.<br /><br /><div style="font-size:75%;color:#ccc;">' . htmlspecialchars($e) . '</div>';
    }

?>
```

The file_get_contents_curl csblogfeed.php contains, the blog is working fine and displays correctly in the below URL.

```
<?php

echo file_get_contents('http://www.coordsport.com/blog/feed/');

?>
```

Comment: `file_get_contents_curl()` isn't a native PHP function.

Comment: @HPierce My first attempt, am I coding this in the wrong way? thanks.

Comment: I can't say for sure - hence the comment as opposed to an answer. What I can say is that you're comparing `file_get_contents()` to `file_get_contents_curl()` like they're the same. `file_get_contents()` is a legitimate PHP function, but `file_get_contents_curl()` isn't. After a quick search, I can see that `file_get_contents_curl()` is apparently a common Wordpress thing, so I suppose it's possible Wordpress brings it in as part of an extension - I've never worked with Wordpress, so I wouldn't know for sure.

Comment: Blank output from your PHP script so probably a fatal error.  Add the usual `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the top of your scripts and see if you're getting any errors or warnings.

Comment: @drew010 Thank you Drew. Good Idea. I do get an error message, although I'm very amateur to this. Any ideas? or is it to broad?

Comment: @drew010 `Notice: file_get_contents(): send of 26 bytes failed with errno=104 Connection reset by peer in /home/sites/coordsport.com/public_html/csblogfeed.php on line 3 Notice: file_get_contents(): send of 2 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe in /home/sites/coordsport.com/public_html/csblogfeed.php on line 3 `

Comment: I can't quite tell but is one of those scripts fetching the other which then fetches the other again?  Are you timing out because it's going in an infinite loop trying to read the feed?

Comment: @drew010 Hmm I see your point, the script fetches another and then executes, although I'm not sure on an alternative method. I appreciate the comments